# msg pack scipy ckdtree - build custom serializer

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, msgpack

I need to custom serialize a ckdtree object with message pack since it is not serializeble by default.

`from scipy.spatial.ckdtree import cKDTree`

```
    with open(msgpack_file, 'wb') as f:
        msgpack.dump(tree, f)
```

`TypeError: Cannot serialize <scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree object at 0x7f7d5c978690>`

I am using python2 (don't blame me) if it matters.

Comment: It looks like you have access to the data in the cKDTree, which themselves may be serializable, specifically `cKDTree.data` appears to just be a `ndarray`.

Comment: correct, but the other attributes seem to be C++ classes. Especially I need to serialize the tree structure which I do not find the propper handle for.